# Should I level this old linoleum tile floor out before carpets?

Tags: flooring, carpet, linoleum

We are putting carpets in this room which when we took up the old carpets revealed this old linoleum tile floor. When taking up the tack strips and such some of the tiles cracked and left just the black glue (i think?) on the concrete on a lot of the borders of the room where the tack strips where. Also the entrance into the basement (pictured below) has a bit of a dip as well where the tile ends and wood near the steps begins. The tiles are pretty darn thin and only on the borders of the room, and wasn't sure if this would prevent the carpets from being installed correctly with even tack strips or cause for it to feel weird to walk on. If so, how could I flatten this out in a day or so (carpets Wednesday) if possible?

My research so far has led me to maybe filling the dips with ardex feather finish? When they install tack strips over those with nails would that break or crack the feather finish? Thanks for any help!

Photos of floor, the white on the floor is drywall dust/dried mud: https://imgur.com/a/mtFJvgE

Comment: Soft flooring can take floors being not flat.  If it does not bother you walking on it it usually fine.  The tack strips should be okay.  Hard flooring(tiles, wood) do want flat floors.

Comment: Note that may be asbestos tile.

Comment: If it _is_ asbestos tile, the best thing to do is leave it undisturbed.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you plan on a thin commercial glue down carpet, the floors need a sweeping before being carpeted.

With even a cheep re-bond padding under carpeting, you should not notice any of the issues you noted.